# Point Subdomain to another application on another domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, subdomain, redirection, dns-server

I'm not a very experienced Server Administrator and I'm trying to set up a new one I just got.

I'm Using IIS7 and DNS Server

What I need is that a url such as: mail.domainA.com points to www.domainB.com/webmail
And I want to do this for all other domains... I want all of my domains that start with mail., point to www.domainB.com/webmail

**In short:** I need a Subdomain to redirect to another URL...

An improvement would be to let the subdomain as it is on the address bar on the redirection, if possible...

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CNAME` record to point mail.domainA.com to mail.domainB.com. Is that what you're trying to get at?

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't solve the problem.  CNAME records kind of alias DNS names, but you can't used them to redirect to an actual URL complete with a path.

Comment: Actually this is not really what i need.. What I need is to point mail.domainA.com to www.domainB.com/webmail

Answer (score 0):

DNS will not give you the option to forward clients into virtual directories inside IIS, CNAME records can help you use different names for the same site or IP, but can't help you into paths.

In this case you will need to use URL redirection features in IIS, take a look at this powerful tool from Microsoft, this should help you get what you want.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Comment: This might be the answer I'm looking for... I'll look deep into It